# How to add a cursor trail in an HTML email

Tags: javascript, html, html-email

Does anyone know a method for which i could add a cursor trail such as the one at http://rainbow.arch.scriptmania.com/scripts/flower_cursor_trail.html to an email to be sent through gamil/outlook? So far, just copy pasting javascript seems to be a dead end.

Comment: I would be pretty scared if js at all was allowed in emails.

Comment: Please don't for the sake of those who do not want to relive cursor trails and the marquee tag

Comment: zomg plz figur this out

Answer (score 2):

Javascript won't work in an email. Your only shot is the CSS [`cursor`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/cursor) property which would be along the lines of:

```
<style>
  body { 
    cursor: url("https://somesite.com/rose.cur"), auto 
  }
</style>
```

Comment: And even then, some clients like gmail will completely scrap the body and style tags of the email, so the cursor will stay the same. And, while I have not tested it, I have a feeling that most mail clients don't allow such styling...